Histogram metric with labels/tags
I have the following Java snippet that I am using to publish histogram metrics
public class MessageConsumer {

    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    private NormalRandomGenerator serviceResponseTimeSecondsGenerator;
    Timer responseTimeSeconds;

    @Autowired
    public MessageConsumer(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
        this.serviceResponseTimeSecondsGenerator =  new NormalRandomGenerator(0.5, 0.1);
        this.responseTimeSeconds = Timer
                .builder("processing_duration")
                .serviceLevelObjectives(
                        Duration.ofMillis(100),
                        Duration.ofMillis(200),
                        Duration.ofMillis(300),
                        Duration.ofMillis(400),
                        Duration.ofMillis(500),
                        Duration.ofMillis(600),
                        Duration.ofMillis(700),
                        Duration.ofMillis(800),
                        Duration.ofMillis(900),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1100),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1200),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1300),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1400),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1500))
                .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(1500))
                .register(this.meterRegistry);
    }

  
    @KafkaListener(topics = "hist")
    public void histListen(String message) throws InterruptedException {
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, String> r = new Gson().fromJson(message, type);
        String id = r.get("id");
        String pod = r.get("pod");
        long responseTimeMillis = (long) (serviceResponseTimeSecondsGenerator.normalRandom() * 1_000);
        log.info("Received message: {}, will say responseTime is {}", r, responseTimeMillis);
        responseTimeSeconds.record(Duration.ofMillis(responseTim

My issue is that I am not able to find a way to add the tags that whose values I know at runtime when publishing.
I need to create grafana dashboard and need to do the grouping say on "id" level. Unless I can put that tag/label, I wont be able to. How do I handle that? Or it is not supported?

Create a new Timer instance (with the builder) each time you record the metric (along with the key-value tags)
